# Как объединить данные из нескольких микросервисов?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, кэширование

У меня есть несколько микросервисов (например, их 3), назову их А, Б и В. Все они подключены к одной БД (Postgres), и для каждого микросервиса в БД есть своя схема со своими таблицами. В каждом микросервисе хранятся определенные данные по заявке (будем считать, что я работаю с какими-то заявками), то есть в А хранится информация об изменяемых полях, в сервисе Б - о неизменяемых, и в В - еще какая-то информация (это все примерно). И сейчас мне нужно фильтровать заявки по разным полям, то есть мне надо будет сходить в каждый сервис и там отфильтровать заявку.
Фильтрация для процесса, который я описал - в принципе легкая и нет ничего такого в том, чтобы походить по сервисам и сделать фильтрацию. Но у меня вопрос: есть ли возможность как-то объединить данные из всех трех микросервисов и делать фильтрацию только в этом (новом сервисе?)? Слышал что-то про Apache Ignite Cache, но не знаю, в правильную ли сторону я копаю... То есть по сути я хочу сделать что-то вроде кэша.
Буду рад любым предложениям!

Comment: а вы уверены, что вы не переусложнили себе задачу и что ваше разделение на сервисы несет исключительно искусственный характер(т.е. данное разделение не имело под собой оснований)?.. точно сказать нельзя, потому что это не конкретная реализация, а умозрительное описание сервисов...но на слух звучит как-то не очень.

Comment: Тем не менее существует ряд паттернов микросервисной архитектуры, которые описывают похожую ситуацию. В таких случаях часто создают сервис `Г`(такая вот у нас следующая буква в алфавите) который является фасадом для ряда операций агрегации данных с нескольких сервисов.

Comment: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html

Comment: https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html